# Increments of Lipschitz function do not satisfy an operator bound

Tags: real-analysis, lipschitz-functions, bounded-variation, rough-path-theory, p-variation

Claim: Let $V: [0, T] (\subset \mathbb{R}) \to \mathbb{R}$ be a Lipschitz continuous function, i.e. $$|V(x,y)|:=|V(x)-V(y)| \leq K_1 | x - y |$$ for all $x,y$ in $[0, T]  $, where $V(.,.)$ denotes the difference between values of $V$ and $K$ is a constant. Then, it follows that the difference can be bounded, i.e there exists a $\tilde{K}$ such that

$$ \sup_{x,y,x’,y’ \in [0,T] | x>y, x’>y’}| V(x,y) - V(x’,y’)| \\ 
\leq \tilde{K} \sup_{x,y,x’,y’ \in [0,T] | x>y, x’>y’} | ( x - y) - (x’- y’) | \\
= \tilde{K}  T $$

**I know there is a chance this may be false from academic** *vox populi*, **can you find a counterexample?**

This post here is a follow-up to this question, so more background can be found there. I believe this specific case is more tractable: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4266346/how-to-prove-lipschitz-functions-are-not-lipschitz-in-the-p-variation-metric

Comment: Isn't $\sup |(x-y)-(x'-y')| = \infty$?

Comment: @angryavian Not at all, if you see the referred question you may understand why this is helpful, as I’m considering the specific case where $ X_s, Y_s$ are just the constant paths equal to $s$  for all $s\in [0,T]$.

Comment: @angryavian However, you were close to making an important observation: this supremum could indeed be simplified, and I have just done so.

Comment: Your estimate is true, since you are working on the interval $[0,T]$.

Comment: What estimate? The supremum, yes, but what justifies the inequality?